# Grub does not load after bios update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bios

I use Ubuntu dual boot with Windows. I recently updated my BIOS from the Acer official website for increased performance, but after updating the BIOS, I am not able to boot Ubuntu. Earlier I used the Windows Boot Manager screen to boot to Ubuntu which appeared after I pressed F12 on my laptop. The boot screen does not show the option for Ubuntu.

Comment: BIOS/UEFI updates often reset UEFI/BIOS settings back to defaults. You may have to re-enable trust on the Ubuntu/grub .efi boot files. With BIOS I had many settings and took photos. With  my newer UEFI desktop, it lists changes it makes when saving, so I document those to make it easier next time I update UEFI.

Answer (score 13):

I have encountered a similar problem. This worked for me.

1. Log-in to Windows using your Administrative account.
   Right click on windows icon and select `command prompt(admin)`.
   Run this from the command prompt:
   `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`
   This will make Grub the default boot manager. Then in the Grub menu, you will find both Windows and Ubuntu.
2. If in the Grub menu you could not find Windows bootloader then, select the `advanced option` (which is just below `Ubuntu`) in Grub menu. Then select `Ubuntu(Recovery Mode)`. There you will find `update grub`. Select it and press `enter`. It will fix the problem and then in `Grub` menu there will be `Windows boot loader`.
   http://myviewsonfoss.blogspot.in/2018/05/how-to-fix-grub.html

Comment: I just discovered that there was a Unknown device option also present in the boot manager and when selected it boots to Ubuntu

Comment: In which boot manager? Grub or Windows? Anyway, could you find both windows & Ubuntu there? Your comment lacks specific info. Please provide in details. Thanks.

Comment: It was a BIOS boot manager with two options : 'Windows BOOT Manager' and 'Unknown Device'

Comment: The first step works! Just copy and paste! Tried many other methods but this one finally works! Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to check if `\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` is a correct boot path? Would `bcdedit` accept an incorrect path?

Comment: @lolesque it seems `bcdedit` accept anything, you have to mount the volume `mountvol P: /S` then list all directories using `dir P:\EFI` and make sure `grubx64.efi` exists in the selected folder. I use KDE neon, so I had to change the command to `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\neon\grubx64.efi` because the ubuntu folder doesn't have the `grubx64.efi` file.

Comment: "The specified command line is not valid." - that's all folks

Answer (score 3):

This happens because on updating BIOS, its preferences and settings changes to default i.e. mode gets set to Legacy mode instead of UEFI mode, also the order of UEFI is reset to put windows first and ubuntu later so just switching mode won't work, you will also have to change order.
Follow these steps(f1 or f2 keys may differ on different laptops)

```
1. Restart System and enter BIOS (using f2 key or other)
2. Change the mode from Legacy to UEFI
3. Change the order of UEFI to put Ubuntu on top, atop Windows. This will ensure that grub menu is loaded on startup.
```

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me:

1) Enter BIOS.

2) Change startup priority so Ubuntu goes first (on top).

This is a similar solution to that from [arnav](https://askubuntu.com/users/912542/arnav). But I had no need to change other UEFI settings, only the boot priority.

Comment: This is the best and simple answer. All other answers add unnecessary complexities

Comment: Useless if the disk doesn't even show up in the HDD boot list at all, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Boot into Live Ubuntu flash drive. R. click desktop and Open Terminal.

Enter commands:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair` then

`sudo apt-get update` then

`sudo apt-get install boot-repair`

Once installed, run command: `boot-repair` and follow the instructions and wait for program to complete. You should get a message whether boot-repair was successful.

If so, restart your computer, go into BIOS and check that Ubuntu exists as an HDD option, and ensure it's first boot option. Then save BIOS settings and restart computer.